# How to know the flow of execution for Apache Camel Components that have the same source and destination Endpoint?

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have some program, for example :

**1.Component A**

```
.from("Direct:start")
.to("Direct:end")
```

**2.Component B**

```
.from("Direct:start")
.to("Direct:end")
```

**3.Component C**

```
.from("Direct:start")
.to("Direct:end")
```

**Component D**

```
.from("Direct:end")
.to("Direct:x")
```

Components A, B and C have the same source and destination endpoints.

**I am unsure of how the execution flows? I am wondering:**

**1.** In which order they execute?

**2.** Will Component D will execute 3 times or any other criteria to determine it's execution?

**3.** Ff component D only executes once, why?

Comment: Formatting and grammatical refinements.

Comment: The question is difficult to understand in its current form, maybe you should make it closer to the reality of what you're trying to do? First you write ".from(...)" when you probably mean "from(...)" (no "."). But you cannot have several routes consuming from the same direct endpoint so you should really tell us what's the actual type of endpoint here. Finally keep in mind that Camel is message-driven; if you don't inject any message anywhere, then it's likely that nothing will happen (except for endpoints that are polling or triggered at regular intervals but again: please be more specific)

Comment: Thanks for Responding.                                                                                           
I thought Multiple Components have the same endpoint in From() but it is not true. I got to know there are different endpoints for each component after placing SOP Statements after From() and before to().